# How to show my spinner within one fragment

Tags: java, android, spinner

I am on creating an application and at the moment, I have created two fragments which is going to be a "navigation" sort of thing. On the second of the two fragments, I have put a spinner on which is where the user would be able to select a particular option. All of the spinners have unique ID's but the findViewById method cannot be resolved

All of the strings are in the strings xml file and when I tried this spinner in my testing app, it worked

```
public class Frag2 extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag2_layout, container, false);

        Spinner spinner = findViewById (R.id.spinner1);
        ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.insulin, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String text = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
}
```

The spinner should work within the one fragment and then I would like to have it another few times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fragment you're dealing with, not an activity. `Fragment` doesn't extend `Context` or `View` classes and does not have this `findViewById` method.

What you should do is to move your code from `onCreateView` to `onViewCreated` which gets a reference to the root view as a parameter. Then use the same method but with that view, as below:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Spinner spinner = view.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ...
}
```

---

Another thing you may do is replacing:

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag2_layout, container, false);

    Spinner spinner = findViewById (R.id.spinner1);
    // I'm not sure how you didn't see all errors when writing code after a return statement.

    ...
}
```

With:

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag2_layout, container, false);

    Spinner spinner = view.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ...

    return view; // after finishing all logic.
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Didn't see that there is also a problem with the `ArrayAdapter`. 
As mentioned in [Csongi77](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55874128/10470378) answer, you need to to instantiate the adapter properly. Again, the fragment cannot use as context, you must use the containing activity for that:

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.insulin, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```

`ArrayAdapter.createFromResource` creates and returns a new adapter and currently you just disposing it immediately by not saving its reference.

Comment: So after the `Spinner spinner = view.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);` line, the only error which I am getting now is on the `ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(context: this, R.array.insulin, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);` line. The frag2 class within the final bracketed section says that the error is an incompatible type - Android Studio comes back with "error: incompatible types: Frag2 cannot be converted to Context" 

The rest of the code has no errors now.

Answer (score 0):

I think first you should instantiate adapter like this: `ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.insulin, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);` please let me know if it works. Regards, Csongi